# ActionMailer instance method being used like class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a brief snippet from the guide on ActionMailer

```
    class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://example.com/login"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end

end
```

And in the controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So why is Rails trying to confuse rubyist with instance methods as class methods? I assume they've overridden missing method, but it just serves to confuse! Or am I missing something here?

ie why not define welcome_email as def *self*.welcome_email(user)

Answer (score 5):

If it was `#self.welcome_email` you'd have to create an instance of the class yourself, which requires some configuration for all the default params etc.  Rails is just providing factory methods of the same name.

From a quick look at the source code, you're right, it does seem to use `method_missing`, where the mailer is actually created with:

mailer = TheMailer.new(:welcome_email, *args)

Rails does a lot of "voodoo" things like this, generally just to save the amount of code you write.  Just changing `#welcome_email` to be a class method would not give you an instance.

Comment: well then rails should continue with having a 'create' or 'deliver' prepended to method name when invoking the mailer. Deprecating those (Rails3) in favor of crazy vudoo is just going to create crazy vudoo developers who think they know ruby but they really dont

Comment: Did you have a question, or just want to voice your opinion? ;)  It seems like you've created a topic with a rhetorical question, which you're not really supposed to do and will likely be closed.

Comment: it was a question - but based on the answer that its 'voodoo' rather than some real logical reason - i guess it does look to be irrelevant.